# Empty Object for a variable when debugging node

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

For my node project I have a dependency for the module `node-config`.
At the very beginning of my project's entry point I set `global.conf = require('config')`.
When I start the debugger in vs-code and check the value of `conf` it seems to be an empty object.
But when my project starts without debugger attached and just console.log for `conf` it has the value expected.

For example:

**api.js**

```
...
global.conf = require('config');  
const utils = require('./lib/utils');
...
```

**utils.js**

```
...  
exports.redisClient = new Redis(conf.session.connection);   
...
```

Although when running the project `conf.session.connection` has the expected value when running the debugger it throws the above error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
TypeError: Cannot read property 'connection' of undefined
```

Comment: I had a similar problem in vs code with java objects appearing empty when examining them through the debugger, but the code works normally. Apparently the object only appears to be empty/all nulls. Did you figure this one out?